# is there any simpler coding in python for encoding and decoding using dictionary data structure

Tags: python, list, dictionary-comprehension

The concept here is encoding and decoding using dictionary data structure. can anyone help me to do this even better and simpler?
              or Is there any build in functions to perform encoding and decoding using dictionary data structure?

```
 qwerty_encrypt={'a':'q','b':'w','c':'e','d':'r','e':'t','f':'y','g':'u','h':'i','i':'o','j':'p','k':'a','l':'s','m':'d','n':'f','o':'g','p':'h','q':'j','r':'k','s':'l','t':'z','u':'x','v':'c','w':'v','x':'b','y':'n','z':'m','1':'9','2':'8','3':'7','4':'6','5':'5','6':'4','7':'3','8':'2','9':'1','0':'0'}
    msg=input('enter yuor msg:').lower()
    #encrypt_func
    def enigma_encrypt(msg):
        a=list(msg.split(' '))
        li=[]
        for i in a:
            li.append(list(i))
        li2=[]
        li4=[]
        for i,j in enumerate(li):
            li3=[]
            for k,l in enumerate(j):
                li3.append(qwerty_encrypt[l])
            li2.append(li3)
        for m in li2:
            li4.append(''.join(m))
        after_encrypt=(' '.join(li4))
        return after_encrypt
    def enigma_decrypt(msg):
        a=list(msg.split(' '))
        li=[]
        for i in a:
            li.append(list(i))
        li2=[]
        li4=[]
        for i,j in enumerate(li):
            li3=[]
            for k,l in enumerate(j):
                for n in qwerty_encrypt:
                    if qwerty_encrypt[n]==l:
                        li3.append(n)
            li2.append(li3)
        for m in li2:
            li4.append(''.join(m))
        after_encrypt=(' '.join(li4))
        return after_encrypt
    print('After encrytion:',enigma_encrypt(msg),'\nAfter decryption:',enigma_decrypt(enigma_encrypt(msg)))
```

Comment: Why use so many lists? msg would be a string which is iterable. I would make a decryption dict as well. then pretty much a two liner for loop outputs your decrypted message and encrypted message. also {" ":" "} is a valid dict

Answer (score 3):

You can use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) in conjunction with [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
qwerty_encrypt = {'a': 'q', 'b': 'w', 'c': 'e', 'd': 'r', 'e': 't', 'f': 'y',
                  'g': 'u', 'h': 'i', 'i': 'o', 'j': 'p', 'k': 'a', 'l': 's',
                  'm': 'd', 'n': 'f', 'o': 'g', 'p': 'h', 'q': 'j', 'r': 'k',
                  's': 'l', 't': 'z', 'u': 'x', 'v': 'c', 'w': 'v', 'x': 'b',
                  'y': 'n', 'z': 'm', '1': '9', '2': '8', '3': '7', '4': '6',
                  '5': '5', '6': '4', '7': '3', '8': '2', '9': '1', '0': '0'}

qwerty_decrypt = {value: key for key, value in qwerty_encrypt.items()}
assert len(qwerty_decrypt) == len(qwerty_encrypt)

table_encrypt = str.maketrans(qwerty_encrypt)
table_decrypt = str.maketrans(qwerty_decrypt)

msg = 'Hello Stack Overflow'.lower()

print('After encryption:', msg.translate(table_encrypt))
print('After decryption:',
      msg.translate(table_encrypt).translate(table_decrypt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though @myrmica code was simple and easy to understand,

But here is my try in the same way with less lists. I hope this is what you expected.

```
qwerty_encrypt={'a':'q','b':'w','c':'e','d':'r','e':'t','f':'y','g':'u','h':'i','i':'o','j':'p','k':'a','l':'s','m':'d','n':'f','o':'g','p':'h','q':'j','r':'k','s':'l','t':'z','u':'x','v':'c','w':'v','x':'b','y':'n','z':'m','1':'9','2':'8','3':'7','4':'6','5':'5','6':'4','7':'3','8':'2','9':'1','0':'0'}
msg=input('enter yuor msg:').lower()
print (msg)
def enigma_encrypt(msg):
    enc=[]
    for i in msg:
        if i!=' ':
            enc.append(qwerty_encrypt[i])
        elif i==' ':
            enc.append(" ")
    return "".join(enc)

def enigma_decrypt(msg):
    ms=enigma_encrypt(msg)
    dec=[]
    for j in ms:
        for u,v in qwerty_encrypt.items():
            if j!=' ' and v==j:
                dec.append(u)
            elif j==' ':
                dec.append(" ")
                break
    return "".join(dec)

print('After encrytion:',enigma_encrypt(msg)+"\n"+'After decrytion:',enigma_decrypt(msg))
```

```
Output:

After encryption: itssg lzqea gctkysgv
After decryption: hello stack overflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the qwerty_encrypt to add null as blank space.
It goes like that:

```
qwerty_encrypt={'a':'q','b':'w','c':'e','d':'r','e':'t','f':'y','g':'u','h':'i','i':'o','j':'p','k':'a','l':'s','m':'d','n':'f','o':'g','p':'h','q':'j','r':'k','s':'l','t':'z','u':'x','v':'c','w':'v','x':'b','y':'n','z':'m','1':'9','2':'8','3':'7','4':'6','5':'5','6':'4','7':'3','8':'2','9':'1',' ':' '}

#encoding
def enigma_encrypt(msg):

    encode = []
    msg = msg.lower()

    for words in msg:
        chars = [char for char in words]
        for k,v in qwerty_encrypt.items():
            if chars[0] == k:#extract char from single list
                encode.append(v)    

    return ''.join(encode)  

#decoding 
def enigma_decrypt(encrypted):

    decode = []

    for code in encrypted:
        chars = [char for char in code]
        for k,v in qwerty_encrypt.items():
            if chars[0] == v: #extract char from single list
                decode.append(k)

    return ''.join(decode)
```

This is what happens:

```
encrypt = enigma_encrypt('Welcome Shenbga')
print(encrypt)
vtsegdt litfwuq

dencrypt = enigma_decrypt('vtsegdt litfwuq')
print(dencrypt)
welcome shenbga
```

[image]

Comment: It doesnt handle spaces in the sentence. @powerPixie

Comment: @SivaShanmugam  I checked again. It's necessary to use the qwerty_encrypt I edited, with the two blank spaces I've added at the end. You can see the print of the code working.